# How to add a map into another map in freemarker templete

Tags: freemarker

I have two maps and I want to add one into another like we do using `putAll` in groovy or java code. We can put key and value pairs to map like following way:

```
<#assign key=value in mapname>
```

but I want to put a map into another map.

Is that feasible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's `<#assign map1 = map1 + map2>`. (Don't add too many maps like that though, as it doesn't modify the existing maps but creates a new object. The creation of the new map is fast, but it will be a bit slower to read as the source maps, as it will look up keys in both.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this is not working in my case. In my case, map1 and map2 are the objects of a class which implements Map<String, Object>, Serializable.

Comment: And what's the problem in that case?

Comment: my actual code is: `<#assign uiLabelMap1 = Static["org.ofbiz.base.util.UtilProperties"].getResourceBundleMap("exampleUiLabels1", locale)>
                <#assign uiLabelMap2 = Static["org.ofbiz.base.util.UtilProperties"].getResourceBundleMap("exampleUiLabels2", locale)>
                <#assign uiLabelMap = uiLabelMap1 + uiLabelMap2/>`. The above mentioned method- 'getResouceBundleMap' returns the object of the class which implements Map<String, Object>, Serializable.

Comment: and the error message I get on console is- uiLabelMap  [in template "DataResource:SNA_CMS_DECORATOR" at line 291, column 77]

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
 - Failed at: ${uiLabelMap.BuynowSearch}  [in template "DataResource:SNA_CMS_DECORATOR" at line 291, column 75]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core.NonHashException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
 at freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:45)
 at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:76)
 at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString...........so on..

Comment: I think the beginning of the error message is missing.